# Access labeled region from cv::connectedComponents

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

Is there a good way of accessing specific regions labeled by cv::connectedComponents? For example, I have identified three regions white regions in a binary image and they are labeled 1, 2, 3. How to do calculations (e.g variance in one direction) only on region with label 2?

Answer (score 2):

You should use cv::connectedComponentsWithStats. Then you can loop through each label and use CC_STAT_LEFT, CC_STAT_TOP, CC_STAT_WIDTH, and CC_STAT_HEIGHT to obtain bounding box for each region. More info here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp

Extracted from the link:

```
    for(int l = 0; l < (int) nlabels; ++l){
        int *row = (int *) &statsv.at<int>(l, 0);
        row[CC_STAT_LEFT] = INT_MAX;
        row[CC_STAT_TOP] = INT_MAX;
        row[CC_STAT_WIDTH] = INT_MIN;
        row[CC_STAT_HEIGHT] = INT_MIN;
        row[CC_STAT_AREA] = 0;
    }
```